# Как убрать трение в Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Чтобы убрать трение при столкновении со стенами я добавлял колайдеру персонажа физический материал и в нём убирал Friction на 0, но из-за отсутсвия трение персонаж начинал скользить по поверхности земли после остановки движения. А если Friction на 1, то сколькожение пропадало, но персанаж растревает при контакте со стенами. Читал на форумах, что скольжение происходит из-за перемещения персонажа через Transform и нужно делать через velocity, но почему-то у меня это не сработало.

Условие для движения персонажа.

```
if (_joystick.Horizontal != 0 && !_isAttacking && _health > 0)
    {
        _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(_joystick.Horizontal * _speed, _rigidbody.velocity.y);
        _effect.SetActive(true);
        _animator.SetInteger("StateSwordsman", 2);
    }
```

Comment: Только 0 и 1? А .09f 0.85f 0.8f?... нет никак?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать два коллайдера, на верхний наложить физический материал(в нем все на 0) и нижний оставить как есть и ничего в него не добавлять. Таким образом персонаж не будет прилипать к стенам, благодаря верхнему коллайдера, и скользить не будет так как в низу коллайдер совершенно другой.  [image: Должно быть так]

Answer (score 1):

Попробую Вам объяснить.
Делайте по пунктам.

1. Создайте 2 Physics Material 2D:

   - назовите первый no_Friction и настройки Friction = 0; Bounciness = 0.
   - назовите второй full_Friction и настройки Friction = 100; Bounciness = 0.
2. В своём скрипте создайте две ссылки на материалы:

   ```
   public PhysicsMaterial2D noFriction;
   public PhysicsMaterial2D fullFriction;
   ```
3. В этом же скрипте создайте метод:

   ```
   public void SetFriction()
     {     
         if(здесь условие, в котором ваше ускорение равно == 0)            
        {           
        _rigidbody.sharedMaterial = fullFriction;                
        } else         
         {         
         _rigidbody.sharedMaterial = noFriction;
         }
        }
   ```
4. Поместите метод SetFriction() в метод Update() для проверки(далее зависит от структуры кода). Сохраните скрипт => идите в Unity.
5. В инспекторе, в полученном скрипте у вас появилось два новых поля noFriction и fullFriction. Поместите в них ваши материалы из ПУНКТА №1(выше) соответственно.
6. Запускайте.

По факту скрипт заменяет материалы в момент, когда ваше ускорение либо = 0, либо != 0